# Training only once in SVM python

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I am working on a project related to detection of emotion from human faces. I am using SVM to train the images first and use this trained data to predict for a new image. But I have to train all the tme before testing a new image. Is there any way to store the trained data and use it everytime to test a new image?

```
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, tol=1e-3)
def train():
    train_data,train_label = trainfiles()
    data = np.array(train_data)
    label = np.array(train_label)
    clf.fit(data,label)
```

Comment: When you try a new image, do you need to input new training data ? 
Or do you just need a way to save your model and use it afterwards on test data ?

Comment: @MohamedALANI Just save the model once and use it afterwards for testing new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classifiers are just objects that you can dump like like any other :

## save the classifier

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl')
```

## load it again

```
clf = joblib.load('filename.pkl')
```